# What does 80% or 60% of Fresnel zone mean?

Tags: propagation

This refers to the link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_zone
In the link it is mentioned that:

The rule of thumb is that the primary Fresnel zone would ideally be 80% clear of obstacles, but must be at least 60% clear.

The question is what is 80% or 60% is it the volume or the cross-sectional area or something else?

Comment: It is cross sectional area, although it may be Gaussian weighted by the distance from the direct line of sight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the cross sectional area of obstructions in the Fresnel Zone that matters.

Most of the signal power travels in the first FZ. If you obstruct 20 to 40% of that, the remaining 80 to 60% amounts to about 1 to 2dB loss. For 'most' link budgets, that would be acceptable. Rules of thumb is about what 'most' people would find acceptable.

The nice thing about wikipedia is that they tend to give references for claims made in the text. In the text where they mention 40% or 20% obstruction, they refer to this citation [1]

> Coleman, Westcott, David, David (2012). Certified Wireless Network Administrator Official Study Guide. 111 River St. Hoboken, NJ 07030: John Wiley & Sons, Inc. p. 126. ISBN 978-1-118-26295-5.

where you can find more detail on it.